# Exception during stamps webservice integration "Unmanaged C++ code exception: invalid argument"

Tags: java, web-services, soap, usps

I am doing integration usps shipping rate quote and shipping label via stamp's webservices in java. I am able to get rate quote successfully but during shipping label generation I am getting exception "Unmanaged C++ code exception: invalid argument".
I am able to hit request when I tried with soap UI but when I tried to hit same request with java code I am getting above error. I have followed instruction from stamp's web development [guide](http://developer.stamps.com/developer/)

I have first generated java files from wsdl then getting rate quote and using that rate quote response I am setting values in stamp's shipping label API.

Please let me know if you have any idea regarding this. I am stuck here.

Comment: I have tried to change request parameter with different values but still I am not able to get the cause of exception.

Comment: I haven't worked with Stamps before, but you can alternatively use Shippo (https://goshippo.com) and use the Java wrapper (https://github.com/goshippo/shippo-java-client). Much simpler integration & cheaper rates.